# CakePhp forms: how to make a dropdown thats shows all hours with 15 minute increments

Tags: forms, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I want a single dropdown where a user can select an hour/minute value for any 15 minute increment eg:

- 12:15
- 08:45

How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `interval` options. From the book :

> echo $this->Form->input('Model.time', array('type' => 'time',
>   'interval' => 15));

book : http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements

Comment: Hi G.J

This is not quite what Im looking for: I want one dropdown that encompassed all the hours of the day from 00:00 to 23:45 in 15 minute increments.

Thanks for the pointer though I think there is a solution in the docs somewhere..